# How to render and display JSON response for a blog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am very new to jquery and HTML. Am working on a assignment where I have to create a simple blog where questions are posted and users can comment on it.
I have managed to create a database and can now successfully fetch and display data (Questions) in a table. 
However while displaying it as a table, I am not able to handle each question in a discrete manner, and hence unable to decide how a user can select a question and comment on same.
Here is my JSON for Questions(Posts):
[
  {
    "postID": 60,
    "postTitle": "Hello World !!",
    "postDate": 1442552136000,
    "ownerID": 7,
    "postVote": 0
  },
]

And here is how I am fetching it:

```js
function loadUserPosts(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'services/posts?OwnerID='+loggedInUserId,
  method: 'get',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }, 
  success: function(data) {
   console.log("Data arrived");
   for(var index in data){
    var row = "<tr><td>"+data[index].postTitle+"</td><td>"+data[index].postVote+"</td><td><button onclick='myFunction()'>Answer/View</button></td></tr>";
    $("#userTable").append(row);
   }
  }
});
 console.log("loadUserPosts - Fired request");
}
```

```html
      </div>
     <div class="docs-section" id="allPosts">
        <h6><b>Recent Questions</b></h6>
     <table id=userTable></table>     
   </div>
```

When a user selects a question, I want him to be redirected to a new page where the question appears along with is comments.
Table does not appear a clean solution, as I am unable to select each row discretely. 
How can I use a  container for displaying the JSON, iteratively (same div container appears multiple times on page with discrete JSON data)?
Apologies if this is very basic !!

Comment: Have you tried adding data values and using those values to when click fetch using those values?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying that. Due to my limited knowledge in area, I added a button next to each row and onclick() of that, I was calling a function which opening a new page for me. I was unsure how to pass data to that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a user selects a question, I want him to be redirected to a new page where the question appears along with is comments.

Table might be a good solution, you have to add to your `<tr>` element `onclick` action like this

```
var row = "<tr onclick=\"window.location.href='question/" + data[index].postID + "'\">\n\
             <td>" + data[index].postTitle + "</td>\n\
             <td>" + data[index].postVote + "</td>\n\
           </tr>";
```

Then you need to implement method to handle request with URI `question/{id}` which would render page with your question where user could comment, vote, etc.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution to my problem. 
But there seems to be some minor error in above statement, because of which my (#userTable) is not getting rows added. I corrected last tag to </tr> but does not seem to work. Not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Updated my answer, there was a " missing in the first line, just before >\n\

Comment: You are amazing @pzeszko . This is exactly what I wanted, but never knew that I can do it with tables as well. Many thanks !!

Comment: @Kanishk glad I could help - happy coding!